# Triggering a Philips Hue button event by the Hue API

Tags: philips-hue

I have a Hue Dimmer Switch that toggles between a few different scenes when tapping the "on" button repeatedly. I would like to be able to "press" the buttons on the switch programmatically - in essence manipulating a physical press via an API call to the Hue API.

The button (sensor) is registered with these possible events in the API:

```
{
    "state": {
        "buttonevent": 1002,
        "lastupdated": "2023-08-03T20:36:51"
    },
    "productname": "Hue dimmer switch",
    "capabilities": {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "repeatintervals": [
                    800
                ],
                "events": [
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 1000,
                        "eventtype": "initial_press"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 1001,
                        "eventtype": "repeat"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 1002,
                        "eventtype": "short_release"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 1003,
                        "eventtype": "long_release"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 1004,
                        "eventtype": "long_press"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "repeatintervals": [
                    800
                ],
                "events": [
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 2000,
                        "eventtype": "initial_press"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 2001,
                        "eventtype": "repeat"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 2002,
                        "eventtype": "short_release"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 2003,
                        "eventtype": "long_release"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 2004,
                        "eventtype": "long_press"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "repeatintervals": [
                    800
                ],
                "events": [
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 3000,
                        "eventtype": "initial_press"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 3001,
                        "eventtype": "repeat"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 3002,
                        "eventtype": "short_release"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 3003,
                        "eventtype": "long_release"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 3004,
                        "eventtype": "long_press"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "repeatintervals": [
                    800
                ],
                "events": [
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 4000,
                        "eventtype": "initial_press"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 4001,
                        "eventtype": "repeat"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 4002,
                        "eventtype": "short_release"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 4003,
                        "eventtype": "long_release"
                    },
                    {
                        "buttonevent": 4004,
                        "eventtype": "long_press"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would've thought I would be able to manipulate the button state with something like this:

```
HTTP PUT
http://{bridge_ip}/api/{username}/sensors/1/state
{
    "buttonevent": 1002
}
```

But the API responds with

```
[
    {
        "error": {
            "type": 8,
            "address": "/sensors/30/state",
            "description": "parameter, buttonevent, is not modifiable"
        }
    }
]
```

Which leads me to believe its not possible to achieve what I want to. Is there any other way of triggering a button press via the API? Or should this be implemented in a completely different manner?

I know I can just hardcode the scenes and set it for the lights, but I would like for it to behave just like the switch does, with the lights and scenes setup for it.

Answer (score 0):

I double-checked also with the [Hue CLI API V2](https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-api-v2/api-reference/#resource_button__id__put), and the button resource does not seem to allow any modification:

[image: CLIP API V2]

As you mentioned, the only way would be to re-implement the button behavior manually.