# How to manage Hue wall switch actions from API?

Tags: philips-hue

I am struggling with managing a Hue wall switch from an API.

Below there is a button:

https://i.imgur.com/MLwpVh3.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/bV79FfA.jpeg

It is configured to turn on lights in Concentrate mode. I want to change it by API to Bright mode.

This button is available in API by sensors/19, but within there is no information about its Action:

https://gist.github.com/bottega-radek-maziarka/e818a2d73bb0462523f053260a113295

Then, there is no additional API, where this action could be configured. I looked in rules API, but there is nothing there.

Is it possible to configure it from an API? If not, how to do it?

Comment: The API should be in this list: https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-api-v2/api-reference/

Comment: API regarding buttons doesn't have any info about actions as well:
https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-api-v2/api-reference/#resource_button__id__get

Comment: According to [Triggering a Philips Hue button event by the Hue API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76835164/triggering-a-philips-hue-button-event-by-the-hue-api) it is: ".... the only way would be to re-implement the button behavior manually."

Comment: I think that this comment is related to another situation - how to click programmatically. Mine is related to changing the button's action.

Comment: Additional question could be: how to reimplement the button behavior manually?